# DART custom input element

Tags: dart

I'm trying custom input element for work with db.
All work perfectly in Chrome, but not work in IE.

I create test app

```
abstract class DBEdit {
  DBSetValue(String val) {}
}

class DBEditText extends InputElement implements DBEdit {
  String _FieldName = "";

  DBEditText.created() : super.created() {
    this.onClick.listen(doOnClick);
  }

  doOnClick(Event e){
    window.alert("Click");
  }

  @override
  DBSetValue(String val) {
    this.value = val;
  }
}

void main() {
  try {
    document.registerElement('db-edit', DBEditText, extendsTag: "input");
  } catch (e) {
    window.alert("Error registration: " + e.toString());
  }

  DivElement div = querySelector("#play");
  div.appendHtml("<input id='ename' type='date' is='db-edit' size=50>", treeSanitizer: NodeTreeSanitizer.trusted);

  DBEditText eText = querySelector("#ename");
  eText.DBSetValue("2017-03-17");
}
```

In HTML file:

```
<html>
<head>
    ....
    <script src="packages/web_components/webcomponents.min.js"></script>
    <script src="packages/web_components/dart_support.js"></script>
    .....
</head>

  <body>
  <div id="play"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

In result all work in Chrome, but DBSetValue not work in IE, but doOnClick work in IE. IE 11.
Any idea?
If element create not in dart code, all work in IE too.

Comment: What IE version are we talking about? Also, did you make sure to include the polyfills provided by package:web_components?

Comment: IE 11. In my html file a have this:    <script async src="packages/web_components/webcomponents.js"></script>

Comment: Couple of questions: does you main.dart.js script tag come after the two scripts mentioned above (webcomponents + dart_support)? Also, do you see any error in the IE console? What happens when you `print(eText.value);` in IE vs Chrome?

Comment: main.dart.js after two script. In IE - Object doesn't support property or method 'DBSetValue$1'